Python CV2, not writing or reading updated images
I'm trying to write each point of each contour to an image, this probably isn't the most optimal way but I have this:
####### DRAW CONTOURS

        for count, cntr in enumerate(contours):
            print(f"Processing contour {str(count)} of {str(len(contours))}...", end="\r")

            if len(cntr) < 5:
                continue

            x,y = sort_xy(cntr[:,0,0], cntr[:,0,1])

            for i in range(0, len(x)):
                image_path = f"./video_output/{str(i).zfill(10)}.jpg"

                if count > 0: # This doesn't update 
                    updated_image = cv2.imread(image_path)
                    cv2.circle(updated_image, (x[i],y[i]), 2, (0, 255, 0), thickness=1)                 
                else: # This works
                    updated_image = cv2.circle(original_image, (x[i],y[i]), 2, (0, 255, 0), thickness=1)

                if not cv2.imwrite(image_path, updated_image):
                    raise Exception("Could not write image")

I have no problem detecting the contours.
The original image is updated fine, however when I start reading the image in the count > 0 section, it doesn't seem up load previously drawn points, apart from the first contour when it is using the original image.
When visualizing this it just seems to write the current point to the file, but doesn't display any of the others.
Not sure if this makes any sense what so ever?
I've tried outputting the results, and the first contour works fine. The second just isn't saving or loading the extra points. Instead its just showing the current point of the contour and not the previous ones.

Please share a minimal reproducible example including an example input image. your current output and a sketch of what you would expect!

You have a loop in the middle of your code that loops over your x,y points:
for i in range(0, len(x)):

In that loop, you determine the image_path, which is based on the current index of the point you're working on. Note the str(i):
image_path = f"./video_output/{str(i).zfill(10)}.jpg"

Presumably, this means that you will have a different image_path for each point in the contour you're working on. You may want to instead do:
image_path = f"./video_output/{str(count).zfill(10)}.jpg"

Which will instead create a new image for each contour, rather than a new image for each point in each contour. This may not fix your problem wholesale, but it might get you on the right track.

Thank you for this. I am indeed trying to generate a new image per point though. The general idea is to have a set of images in which all contours are being drawn in parallel one point at a time. It doesn't matter that some will have less points and finish earlier though.
